# How can I implement undo system between 0 and 1 values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column named `deleted` which is either `1` or `0`. Also I have this query:

```
UPDATE posts SET deleted = {if it is 0, then replace it with 1 and vice versa}
```

How can I implement that `{if}` statement in MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

To swap the flags the following should do

```
UPDATE posts SET deleted = CASE WHEN deleted=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [IF](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp):

```
UPDATE posts SET deleted = IF(deleted = 0, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this](http://qdosmsq.dunbar-it.co.uk/blog/2013/04/swap-2-values-in-sql-without-using-a-temporary-variable/).

For the record:

```
update bedrock set sex = case sex when 'F' then 'M' when 'M' then 'F' end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update posts set deleted=1-deleted
```

This works by taking the previous value and subtracting it from 1, so it essentially covers the two cases: 0 becomes 1, 1 becomes 0. It is the way to implement the NOT boolean logic when you have an integer with 0 or 1 value.

In certain hardware/software implementations, a simple substraction is lighter than an IF branch, so it is preferable. Don't think sql is such a thing, though.

Comment: A little bit more explanation on why this works would help the OP and future readers, and would prevent it getting flagged as low quality and checked in review.

Comment: All right, thanks for this feedback, sometimes it seems obvious to me.

Comment: As some one who doesn't work with MySQL, I can kind of guess whats happening, and it looks a very clever way to do what the OP wants, but others might be a bit lost as to why it works!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports IF statement.

UPDATE posts
SET deleted = IF(deleted = 0, 1, 0),

Link gives you more info on MYSQL IF() function:
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php